# Change multiple div's on hover another div

Tags: html, css, image, hover, background-image

I've found a lot of similar problems, but none with a solution for mine.

I've got 3 images displayed next to each other. The images are background-image with CSS. I explain why later:

```
<div class="team-photo-container">

<div class="team-photo-wrapper">

    <div class="team-photo david"></div>

    <div class="team-photo charlotte"></div>

    <div class="team-photo timon"></div>

</div>
```

When I hover over the first image (`.david`) I want the background-image of the other two (`.charlotte` and `.timon`) to change. I got this to work with this:

```
.charlotte:hover ~ .david {
background-image: url(../../images/basic-david-right.jpg) !Important;
}

.charlotte:hover ~ .timon {
    background-image: url(../../images/basic-timon-left.jpg) !Important;    
}
```

NOW MY PROBLEM:

I want the same to happen to the other images. So when I hover on `.charlotte` I want the background image for `.david` and `.timon` to change. BUT it only changes `.timon`. When I try the hover code on `.timon`, neither one change...

I think the code doesn't work when the div is in front of the hover div...

I hope you guys understand my question! Sorry for pour English, I'm Dutch.

David

Comment: You can't select a previous element with CSS, you'll need jQuery or Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try some jQuery like so:

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.block', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  that.removeClass('nearTarget').addClass('target');
  $('.block').not(this).addClass('nearTarget').removeClass('target');
}).on('mouseleave', '.block', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  $('.block').removeClass('nearTarget target');
})
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.block.target { background-color: red; }
.block.nearTarget { background-color: #999; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  
  <div id="one" class="block"></div>
  <div id="two" class="block"></div>
  <div id="three" class="block"></div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, if you read the W3C specifications:

> E ~ F ===>  an F element preceded by an E element

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

It's just the next elements that are targeted not previous.
No selector allows you to do what you want.

But you can try something like this:

```
// Hover sibling states
.team-photo-wrapper:hover .charlotte {
    background-image: url(../../images/hover-david-right.jpg);
}

.team-photo-wrapper:hover .timon {
    background-image: url(../../images/hover-timon-left.jpg);    
}

// Basic states
.team-photo-wrapper .charlotte {
    background-image: url(../../images/basic-david-right.jpg) !important;
}
.team-photo-wrapper .timon:hover {
    background-image: url(../../images/basic-timon-left.jpg) !important;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be more straightforward doing it with jQuery:

```
$(".team-photo").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings("div").addClass("hover");
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings("div").removeClass("hover");
});
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3gxhahu/)

As you're using background images, you would want to convert the `hover` class in my Fiddle's CSS to something like this...

```
.david.hover {
    background-image: url(../../images/basic-david-right.jpg) !Important;
}
.timon.hover {
    background-image: url(../../images/basic-timon-right.jpg) !Important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with pure CSS, this might work (Sass code, see [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/HerrBertling/pen/YPmbpj)):

```
.team-photo-wrapper
  width: 400px // or something…
.team-photo
  width: 400px
  height: 200px
  background-size: cover
.david
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/399/200/")
  &:hover
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/150")
.charlotte
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/")
  &:hover
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/150")
.timon
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/401/200/")
  &:hover
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/150")

// Magic part  
.team-photo-wrapper:hover :not(:hover)
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/402/200/")
```

If you need different images for the different people, you could chain the class to the selector, e.g. `.team-photo-wrapper:hover :not(:hover).timon`

Please be careful, the :not selector has a pretty bad performance if used too often…